# Run a script when bluetooth device is connected

Tags: linux-mint, udev, bluetooth

I'm trying to run a script automatically right after a certain bluetooth device is connected. To do so, I tried to create a new UDEV rule. The problem I encounter is that my rule doesn't execute upon establishing the connection.

As of now, my rule contains only the MAC address of the device.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", ATTRS{address}=="a0:b1:c2:e3:f4:56", RUN+="/home/myhome/my_script"
```

How can I find more device details in order to add them to the rule?

When the device is connected, I can see the following UDEV event:

```
$ udevadm monitor
UDEV  [7704849.324977] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12 (bluetooth)
```

Is there any information in the above event that I can leverage?

I place the rule in both UDEV rules places, `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and `/lib/udev/rules.d/`, but still it doesn't run. I'm on a Linux Mint system.

The rule has same permissions as all the other rules in the directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  369 Oct 17 13:07 50-my_bluetooth_rule.rules
```

I also played around with the rule number between 50 and 90. Still, no success.

Comment: Have you run `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` after creating that file?

Comment: @IporSircer Yes I did. Nothing happens.

Comment: Your script should start with `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @GAD3R yes the script is as such. But the problem is the rule doesn't get run at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` to get the `idVendor` and the `idProduct` the write the udev rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-my_bluetooth_rule.rules` as follows:

```
ACTION=="add" , SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxx", ATTR{idProduct}=="yyy", RUN+="/home/myhome/my_script"
```

Run:

```
sudo service udev restart
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Reconnect your bluetooth device. You can use `logger` in your bash script to write messages to `syslog`.

Comment: Your answer guided me to the root problem. It wasn't the inability to pick up the device when connected. The issue was that my script had to be run as my user not root in order to render the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that I had to use `ATTRS{name}` rather than `ATTRS{address}`.
I found this out by issuing:

```
udevadm info -ap /devices/virtual/input/input160/event6
```

More info [here](https://linuxconfig.org/tutorial-on-how-to-write-basic-udev-rules-in-linux).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by listening to `dbus-monitor` and running my script under a particular Bluetooth event. In particular,

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.blueman.Applet',member='MenuChanged'"|
while read -r line; do

notify-send 'my bluetooth keyboard has just connected! High time to run my script'

./my_script.sh

done
```