# How can I run a command, when I press the top button of my Bamboo Ink pen?

Tags: linux, udev, wacom

I've been trying to run a command, when I press the top key on my Bamboo Ink Pen. I realized that it connects via Bluetooth, when I press the button and ceases the connection, when I release it.

I stumbled over [Run a script when bluetooth device is connected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476094/run-a-script-when-bluetooth-device-is-connected) and when I run

```
udevadm monitor --environment --udev --kernel --property
```

and press the button once, I get the following output:

```
KERNEL[5118.647193] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585 (bluetooth)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=4094

UDEV  [5118.657098] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585 (bluetooth)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=4094
USEC_INITIALIZED=5118654305
SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0:3585
SYSTEMD_WANTS=bluetooth.target
SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=bluetooth.target
TAGS=:systemd:

KERNEL[5119.311809] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585 (bluetooth)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=4095

UDEV  [5119.317304] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585 (bluetooth)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=4095
USEC_INITIALIZED=5118654305
SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0:3585
SYSTEMD_WANTS=bluetooth.target
SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=bluetooth.target
TAGS=:systemd:
```

Unfortunately there is no idVendor or idProduct.

When I run

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

though, it complains that the file does not exist.

My `udev rules` looks like this so far.

```
# Run a program when my Bamboo Ink is connected
ACTION=="add" , SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxx", ATTR{idProduct}=="yyy", ATTRS{model}=="Bamboo Ink", RUN+="xournalpp"
```

Guessing the model is "Bamboo Ink", since I found this line in `journalctl -b`

`Feb 26 14:57:35 X380-Yoga kernel: wacom 0005:056A:035F.000C: Unknown device_type for 'Bamboo Ink'. Ignoring.`

So I need to find the idVendor, idProduct and model. Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it:

```
ACTION=="add" , SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585", RUN+="/home/gvb/bin/run-pen-state.sh"
```

What I wanted to do was switch between pen and eraser and in Xournal. The two scripts needed for this are shown below. They need two small utilities: wmctrl and xdotool...

Contents of "run-pen-state.sh" is

```
#!/bin/csh
sudo -u gvb -i /home/gvb/bin/pen-state
```

while "pen-state" itself is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$home=$ENV{'HOME'};
$store=`grep "#state: " ~/bin/pen-state | grep -v store`;
chomp($store);

$command=`export DISPLAY=:0; export XAUTHORITY=$home/.Xauthority; wmctrl -l`;
foreach $line (split(/\n/,$command)){
  if (($line=~ /Xournal/)&&($line=~ /$filename/)){
    $winid=(split(/ /,$line))[0];
  }
}


if($winid){
  system("export DISPLAY=:0; export XAUTHORITY=$home/.Xauthority; wmctrl -i -a $winid");


  if($store =~ /pen/){
    $now="state: eraser";
    system("export DISPLAY=:0; export XAUTHORITY=$home/.Xauthority; xdotool key shift+ctrl+e");
  }else{
    $now="state: pen";
    system("export DISPLAY=:0; export XAUTHORITY=$home/.Xauthority; xdotool key shift+ctrl+p");
  }

  $now="#$now";

  print "$store\n";
  print "$now\n";

  open(SELF,"$home/bin/pen-state");
  read(SELF,$self,-s "$home/bin/pen-state",0);
  close(SELF);
  $self=~ s/$store/$now/;
  open(SELF,">$home/bin/pen-state");
  print SELF $self;
  close(SELF);
}

#state: pen
```

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to discriminate udev rules for the pen/stylus vs touch (on lenovo thinkpad with wayland and wacom)

Answer (score 1):

**Update February 2022:**
I just noticed, with Ubuntu 22.04, Kernel 5.16.8 and Gnome 41.3 it works out of the box. The top button is detected as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>AudioMicMute</kbd> combo which you can use to assign any shortcut in Gnome settings. But I don't know when it started to work.

**Original answer:**
I have nearly the same approach as in the previous answer from Guillaume. But the problem with his answer for me is, that I found no way to distinguish which device triggered the add action of the bluetooth subsystem, so that Guillaume's simple rule also matched when I connected any other device via bluetooth.
But with my Lenovo active pen 2 I noticed that one of two things can happen, whenever I press the top button.

Case 1)
The pen connects and disconnects within one or two seconds. `udevadm monitor` shows only the add and remove action.

Case 2)
After udev's add action the pen is recognized as HID named *Lenovo Active Pen2 Keyboard*. Then it takes about 10 seconds until it is removed.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/bluetooth_event_detected.sh add"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/bluetooth_event_detected.sh remove"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hid", DEVPATH=="/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:17EF:60A8.*", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/bluetooth_event_detected.sh force"
```

So I watch for the add and remove actions in my udev rule, which triggers a script that times how long it takes between an add and the next remove event. If it takes less than 2 seconds it assumes that this was the pen and sets a flag under `/tmp/stylus`.
The same happens in case two when the pen is recognized as HID.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# PATH is not provided in an udev environment
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

DIRECTORY=/tmp/stylus
TSFILE=$DIRECTORY/bluetooth_timestamp
BTN_PRESSED_FLAG=$DIRECTORY/stylus_button_pressed
TIME_DELTA="2"  

ACTION=$1
NOW=$(date +%s)


mkdir -p $DIRECTORY 
chmod 777 $DIRECTORY

if [ "$ACTION" = "add" ]; then
        echo $NOW > $TSFILE                   
elif [ "$ACTION" = "remove" ]; then
        ADDED_TS=$(cat $TSFILE)
        DIFF=$(($NOW-$ADDED_TS))
        echo diff: $DIFF
        # if the time between adding and removing is 
        # 2 seconds or less, we assume the stylus button
        # was pressed
        if [ "$DIFF" -le "$TIME_DELTA" ]; then
                touch $BTN_PRESSED_FLAG          
                chmod 666 $BTN_PRESSED_FLAG 
        fi
elif [ "$ACTION" = "force" ]; then
        touch $BTN_PRESSED_FLAG
        chmod 666 $BTN_PRESSED_FLAG
fi
```

Last I have a simple script autostarted when I log into my desktop environment, that keeps watching for that flag under `/tmp/stylus` and executes `gnome-screenshot -i`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/tmp/stylus/stylus_button_pressed
CMD="gnome-screenshot -i"

while true; do
        if [ -f $FILE ]; then
                echo running command
                $CMD
                rm $FILE
        fi
        sleep 0.1
done
```

Not elegant, but working.